# How to get data dynamically by combining result from Response with dynamic param from route in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

This is the first time I got a task to get object parameter dynamically from the url param. I know I can use `this.$route.params.[somelink-parameter]` to get the url parameter. and I know the way to get and store the response result into a subject such as `this.response = res` for example.

But Here comes the problem:

let say I have a Url like this: `https://myUrl.com/some-campaign/:packageCategory`

I tried to store the param like this:

`const packageCategory = this.$route.params.packageCategory`

and this is the the example of my object from response:

```
{
  packageCategory: {
      promoA: [
         {
            id: promoA-0001
         },
         {
            id: promoA-0002
         },
         {
            id: promoA-0003
         },
         {
            id: promoA-0004
         }
      ],
      promoB: [
         {
            id: promoB-0001
         }
      ],
      promoC: [
         {
            id: promoC-0001
         },
         {
            id: promoC-0002
         },
         {
            id: promoC-0003
         }
      ],
      promoD: [
         {
            id: promoD-0001
         },
         {
            id: promoD-0002
         }
      ],
  }
}
```

what I want to achieve is:

**How to get the data object dynamically from the Url and combine it with the result to get the object from packageCategory based on Url Params**

some way that I tried is something like this:

URL: `https://myUrl.com/some-campaign/promoA`

packageCategory : `promoA`

goals: `to get the object dynamically from the params such as this.packages = result.promoA`

```
{
 promoA: [
  {
   id: promoA-0001
  },
  {
   id: promoA-0002
  },
  {
   id: promoA-0003
  },
  {
   id: promoA-0004
  }
 ],
}
```

1st Try:

```
const packageCategory = this.$route.params.packageCategory;

getPackageCampaign().then((result) => {
 this.packages = `${JSON.parse(result)}.${packageCategory}`;
 console.log("cek result : ", this.packages);
})
```

output give an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

2nd Try:

```
const packageCategory = this.$route.params.packageCategory;

getPackageCampaign().then((result) => {
 this.packages = `${result}.${packageCategory}`;
 console.log("cek result : ", this.packages);
})
```

output:

`[object Object].promoA`

Is it possible to solve this problem with this approach? or is there any other approach to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS you can access object properties with indexer syntax:

```js
let A = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2
  }
}

let B = A['a'] // B = 1
let member = 'b'
let C = A[member] // C === A.b
```

So in your case it's something like this (depends on the real structure of your data ...which is not really clear from your question)

```js
getPackageCampaign().then((result) => {
 // assuming result is already JS object (result of JSON.parse)
 this.packages = result[this.$route.params.packageCategory];
 console.log("result : ", this.packages);
})
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer, after I tried it, it give me error `Cannot read property 'promo80' of undefined` and if I use `result.packageCategory[packageCategory]` isn't it will find the index with `packageCategory value` in the array? I think it is quite different from what I want to achieve since in my case what I want to achieve is to put the `packageCategory` after `result.` to get all of the array data as `packages` objects value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thankyou for your reference, after I read it several time, I just realize that instead of `Dot Objects` approach it is better the second approach using it like `array`, Thankyou for the new knowledge ^.^. Can you update your answer? I will give it a solved mark for it. it works if I make it like this `this.packages = result[packageCategory];`, and I use this for checked the value `console.log("result : ", this.packages);`

Comment: let me know if you updated your answer, once again Thank you ^.^